# Returning self.__dict__ from a method

Tags: python, deep-copy

I am working with a nice little python module from a third party, and I ran across a bit that has got my brain all twisted, and I'm mostly concerned with data integrity.

Quick summary: there is a class method that goes roughly as such:

```
def as_dict(self):
    ##adjust some attributes that don't make sense outside this scope        
    ##... ... ...
    return self.__dict__
```

I am manually using the result of this method, but there are a few places where I pass it on, and I have no idea what those function are actually doing to the returned dict.

Now, is this safe as it is, or could some stray function start messing with my instance attributes? I originally thought that 'self' somehow protected the dataset, and I was passing around a copies of the data, but now I wonder if I am passing around references to instance memory? (there are nested mutables within)

Should I just do instead: `return copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__)`

Comment: Have you tested for the behavior that you have described within your code?

Comment: I have not, and I wouldn't be able to do so fully at this point. I guess some caution was raised while I was editing this function, as it seemed like a problem waiting to happen. Is self.__dict__ treated special in any way, or is it just another dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, the instance dict is perfectly mutable like any other dict. It's unusual to return the dict like that. Perhaps it's indended to be modified outside the instance for some reason. Seems like it's probably a bad design though.

Sometimes people do horrible things like that because they think it's better than using global variables.

Copying isn't really a good fix. It could be very slow, and is just hiding the underlying design problems

An alternative to copying would be to wrap the dict so it can't be modified accidentally.

Comment: The class implementing this method does provide the interface of a dict (although it does not inherit). Includes __getitem__, get, has_key, items,... (again, does not inherit). So has the author already taken the precautions, or is self.__dict__ naked so to speak?

Comment: I dug a bit, I think the 3rd party module is feeding JSON/XML conversions with the dict return value. I imaging they are safe enough for now... thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure about passing a copy, `copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__)` would be the way to go.